# C Socket programming on windows errors on listen but no errno

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking

I've done socket programming in other languages but never dealt with doing it in C directly. I'm trying to set up a simple server to listen on port 8080 under Windows. I'm using the gcc that comes with mingw to compile the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <time.h>

        int main(void) {

        int s;      
        int len;
        char  buffer[1025];  
        struct sockaddr_in servAddr; 
        struct sockaddr_in clntAddr; 

        int clntAddrLen; //length of client socket addre

    //Build local (server) socket add

        memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
        servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servAddr.sin_port = htons(8080);
        servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

       //create socket
        if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) %lt; 0 )){
            perror("Error: Socket Failed!");
                printf("%d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }

    //bind socket to local address and port
        if((bind(s,(struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) %lt; 0))
        {
            perror("Error:bind failed!");
                printf("%d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }

        for(;;)
        {
            len = recvfrom(s,buffer, sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);

            //send string
            sendto(s, buffer, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clntAddr, sizeof(clntAddr));
        }

    }
```

When I run the code it errors out binding but there's no error. This code was taken and slightly modified from this thread: [Windows Socket Programming in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769981/windows-socket-programming-in-c)

But there's no error code. The output prints that there's no error. It fails at the bind and I'm not sure why. I've been piecing together a few different sources. I literally just want something that can do a hello world/3 way handshake in C on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

```
if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0 )){
```

as `<` has higher precedence than `=`. This means that the code will assign `1` or `0` to `s` depending on result of `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0`.
Change to:

```
if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ){
```

Use [`WSAGetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain failure reason, not `errno`. From the MSDN [`bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference page:

> If no error occurs, bind returns zero. Otherwise, it returns SOCKET_ERROR, **and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.**

On Windows [`WSAStartup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must be invoked before any socket functions are called.

Comment: Also, `WSACleanup()` should be run when finishing using sockets.