# makefile error: sys/socket.h no such file or directory under Windows

Tags: c

I am using following makefile below:

```
CC=g++

all: socket.exe

socket.exe: socket.o
    g++ socket.o -o socket.exe

socket.o: socket.cpp
    g++ -c socket.cpp
```

When I run make it show error:

> socket.cpp: sys/socket.h: no such file or directory.

How to fix it? I am working on Windows.

Comment: When you have a compiler error like this, it makes far more sense to show the code for `socket.cpp` than your `Makefile`, don't you think? Also, you're running `g++` from Windows? What is your *actual* build environment, Cygwin?

Answer (score 23):

`<sys/socket.h>` is for UNIX/Linux.

For windows, you use `<Winsock2.h>`. You'll also need to link against `Ws2_32.lib` and call `WSAStartup` to use WinSock.

See also:

- [`socket` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506.aspx) (MSDN)
- [Windows Socket Programming in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769981/windows-socket-programming-in-c) (Stack Overflow)