# Error while creating socket in C (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c, visual-studio, sockets

I am trying to make a client/server homework. I use Visual Studio 2017 and already changed the project settings that i can use sockets ([Windows Socket Programming in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769981/windows-socket-programming-in-c?rq=1)) but now my console always says "ERROR while creating Socket ... : No error"

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <WinSock.h>

void PrintErrorExit(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int randomNumber;
    int sock = 0;
    // Erzeuge das Socket - Verbindung über TCP/IP
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
        PrintErrorExit("ERROR while creating Socket ... "); 


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems:

- First, you need to call [`WSAStartup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) to [initialize Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/initializing-winsock) before you can then use `socket()`.
- Second, you need to compare the return value of [`socket()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket) to `INVALID_SOCKET`, as the documentation says.
- Third, [`perror()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/perror-wperror) does not work with Winsock errors, as your example demonstrates.  `perror()` looks at [`errno`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-doserrno-sys-errlist-and-sys-nerr), which Winsock does not set. Use [`WSAGetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) instead to get the error code of a failed Winsock function, and then you can print it out as needed.

Comment: Third, you need to get a Winsock error code using WSAGetLastError(). Converting Winsock errors to strings is slightly tricky.

Comment: @immibis "*Converting Winsock errors to strings is slightly tricky*" - not really, you can use [`FormatMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) for that, see [How do I retrieve an error string from WSAGetLastError()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400922/)